# Multi-level Muenchian Grouping

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping

I was hoping someone could assist me by pointing me in the right direction with Muenchian grouping.

I have data in the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<LandXML schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2.xsd" version="1.2" date="2013-08-01" time="22:10:15.294-00:00" readOnly="false" language="english">
<Application name="ListechStyleSheet" version="1, 0, 0, 0" manufacturer="LISTech Pty Ltd" manufacturerURL="www.liscad.com">
<Author createdBy="Listech Development Team" />
</Application>
<Project name="LISCAD" desc="OLC ANGLES JULY 2013" />
<Units>
<Metric linearUnit="meter" areaUnit="squareMeter" volumeUnit="cubicMeter" temperatureUnit="celsius" pressureUnit="HPA" />
</Units>
<Survey> 
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0112" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0114" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0113" horizDistance="254.698" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3441" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3429" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3846" horizDistance="275.373" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3854" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3913" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0615" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0627" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4956" horizDistance="174.694" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4955" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0114" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0112" horizDistance="254.697" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3442" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3431" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3848" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3855" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.556" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3914" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0613" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0626" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4955" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4954" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0111" horizDistance="254.697" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0116" horizDistance="254.698" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3441" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3433" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3848" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3857" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3911" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0614" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0627" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4957" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="329.0304" horizDistance="138.077" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00228">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW61" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="148.0017" horizDistance="133.943" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00227">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM06" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="148.0026" horizDistance="133.944" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00227">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM06" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="149.1505" horizDistance="249.106" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00250">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW59" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="149.1451" horizDistance="249.106" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00250">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW59" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="160.2644" horizDistance="260.353" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00252">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW159" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="160.2659" horizDistance="260.353" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00252">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW159" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="244.5944" horizDistance="52.087" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00210">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW60" />
</ReducedObservation>
```

Etc...

I am trying to get output that groups as follows:

```
liscadGM04
                pntRef  GM03    Min azimuth=:”70.0109”
                pntRef  GM03    Max azimuth=:”70.0117”
liscadGM04
                pntRef  SAW53  Min azimuth=:”107.3429”
                pntRef  SAW53  Max azimuth=:”107.3442”
liscadGM04
                pntRef  HB402   Min azimuth=:”309.3845”
                pntRef  HB402   Max azimuth=:”309.3857”

                Etc…..
liscadSAW160
                pntRef  SAW61  Min azimuth=:”10.0112”
                pntRef  SAW61  Max azimuth=:”70.0112”

            Etc…
```

I am struggling to get the XSL code nesting like this, here is an extract of my feeble attempts to date:

```
 <!-- Define a key that uses our element or attribute for grouping -->
<xsl:key name="SetUp" match="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation" use="@setupID" />
<!--<xsl:key name="Target" match="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation/TargetPoint" use="@pntRef" />-->
<xsl:key name="Target" match="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation/TargetPoint" use="concat(@setupID, '|', @pntRef)" />




    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <!-- Create a node set for the current Row item (.) and the first 
         item in the Key of the Current item  Category. Then we check the count to see is it 1 or 2.. 
         If 1, So we've the same item in the node set; We have a new Category.-->
        <xsl:for-each select="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation[count(. | key('SetUp', @setupID)[1]) = 1]">
            <!--<xsl:for-each select="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation/TargetPoint[count(. | key('Target', @pntRef)[1]) = 1]">-->
                <!-- Sort by the Category -->
                <xsl:sort select="@setupID" />
                <xsl:sort select="TargetPoint/@pntRef" />
                <xsl:sort select="@azimuth"/>
                <xsl:value-of select='substring(@setupID,7)' />
                <br />

                <!-- Now loop on the items of this Category, We get them from the Key we defined -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('SetUp', @setupID)">
                <!--<xsl:for-each select="key('Target', @pntRef)">-->
                <!-- Sort by the item Value -->
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        Min
                        <xsl:value-of select="TargetPoint/@pntRef"/>:
                        <xsl:value-of select="@azimuth"/><br />
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                        Max
                        <xsl:value-of select="TargetPoint/@pntRef"/>:
                        <xsl:value-of select="@azimuth"/>
                    </xsl:if>

              <!--</xsl:for-each>-->
          </xsl:for-each>
          <hr />
          <br />
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Lee Morse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, try this key-based solution.  It turns out since you aren't grouping by setupID, it is only a single level of grouping, not a multi-level grouping, and so only one key is needed.  I hadn't noticed that when I started with the variable-based grouping based on your question title.  It produces the identical result as my variable-based solution.  It will occupy less memory, hopefully less enough to work in your environment.

Note also your min/max calculation is overkill and both of my solutions suggest a simpler approach.

```
t:\ftemp>type land.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<LandXML version="1.2" date="2013-08-01" time="22:10:15.294-00:00" readOnly="false" language="english">
<Application name="ListechStyleSheet" version="1, 0, 0, 0" manufacturer="LISTech Pty Ltd" manufacturerURL="www.liscad.com">
<Author createdBy="Listech Development Team" />
</Application>
<Project name="LISCAD" desc="OLC ANGLES JULY 2013" />
<Units>
<Metric linearUnit="meter" areaUnit="squareMeter" volumeUnit="cubicMeter" temperatureUnit="celsius" pressureUnit="HPA" />
</Units>
<Survey> 
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0112" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0114" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0113" horizDistance="254.698" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3441" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3429" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3846" horizDistance="275.373" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3854" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3913" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0615" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0627" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4956" horizDistance="174.694" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4955" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0114" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0112" horizDistance="254.697" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3442" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3431" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3848" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3855" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.556" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3914" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0613" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0626" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4955" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4954" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0111" horizDistance="254.697" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0116" horizDistance="254.698" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3441" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3433" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3848" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3857" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3911" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0614" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0627" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4957" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="329.0304" horizDistance="138.077" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00228">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW61" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="148.0017" horizDistance="133.943" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00227">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM06" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="148.0026" horizDistance="133.944" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00227">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM06" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="149.1505" horizDistance="249.106" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00250">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW59" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="149.1451" horizDistance="249.106" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00250">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW59" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="160.2644" horizDistance="260.353" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00252">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW159" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="160.2659" horizDistance="260.353" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00252">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW159" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="244.5944" horizDistance="52.087" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00210">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW60" />
</ReducedObservation>
</Survey>
</LandXML>
t:\ftemp>call xslt land.xml land.xsl 
liscadGM04
            pntRef  GM03   Min azimuth:70.0111
            pntRef  GM03   Max azimuth:70.0116
liscadGM04
            pntRef  SAW53   Min azimuth:252.3429
            pntRef  SAW53   Max azimuth:252.3442
liscadGM04
            pntRef  HB402   Min azimuth:309.3846
            pntRef  HB402   Max azimuth:309.3857
liscadGM04
            pntRef  GM05   Min azimuth:320.3911
            pntRef  GM05   Max azimuth:320.3917
liscadGM04
            pntRef  SAW144B   Min azimuth:348.0613
            pntRef  SAW144B   Max azimuth:348.0627
liscadGM04
            pntRef  SAW144   Min azimuth:35.4954
            pntRef  SAW144   Max azimuth:35.4957
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW61   Min azimuth:329.0304
            pntRef  SAW61   Max azimuth:329.0304
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  GM06   Min azimuth:148.0017
            pntRef  GM06   Max azimuth:148.0026
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW59   Min azimuth:149.1451
            pntRef  SAW59   Max azimuth:149.1505
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW159   Min azimuth:160.2644
            pntRef  SAW159   Max azimuth:160.2659
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW60   Min azimuth:244.5944
            pntRef  SAW60   Max azimuth:244.5944

t:\ftemp>type land.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="setup-refs" match="ReducedObservation"
         use="concat(@setupID,' ',TargetPoint/@pntRef)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation
          [generate-id(.)=
           generate-id(key('setup-refs',
                           concat(@setupID,' ',TargetPoint/@pntRef))[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@setupID"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="azimuths"
                  select="key('setup-refs',
                              concat(@setupID,' ',TargetPoint/@pntRef))/
                          @azimuth"/>
    <xsl:text>            pntRef  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="TargetPoint/@pntRef"/>
    <xsl:text>   Min azimuth:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$azimuths[not(.>$azimuths)][1]"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;            pntRef  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="TargetPoint/@pntRef"/>
    <xsl:text>   Max azimuth:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$azimuths[not(.&lt;$azimuths)][1]"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use the Muenchian method?  I tell my students that for multi-level grouping I find the variable-based grouping method to be easier to write.

```
t:\ftemp>type land.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<LandXML version="1.2" date="2013-08-01" time="22:10:15.294-00:00" readOnly="false" language="english">
<Application name="ListechStyleSheet" version="1, 0, 0, 0" manufacturer="LISTech Pty Ltd" manufacturerURL="www.liscad.com">
<Author createdBy="Listech Development Team" />
</Application>
<Project name="LISCAD" desc="OLC ANGLES JULY 2013" />
<Units>
<Metric linearUnit="meter" areaUnit="squareMeter" volumeUnit="cubicMeter" temperatureUnit="celsius" pressureUnit="HPA" />
</Units>
<Survey> 
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0112" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0114" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0113" horizDistance="254.698" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3441" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3429" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3846" horizDistance="275.373" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3854" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3913" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0615" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0627" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4956" horizDistance="174.694" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4955" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0114" horizDistance="254.696" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0112" horizDistance="254.697" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3442" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3431" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3848" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3855" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.556" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3914" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0613" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0626" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4955" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4954" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0111" horizDistance="254.697" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="70.0116" horizDistance="254.698" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00251">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM03" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3441" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="252.3433" horizDistance="107.081" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00221">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW53" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3848" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="309.3857" horizDistance="275.374" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00255">
<TargetPoint pntRef="HB402" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3917" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="320.3911" horizDistance="287.557" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00258">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM05" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0614" horizDistance="108.041" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="348.0627" horizDistance="108.040" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00222">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144B" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadGM04" azimuth="35.4957" horizDistance="174.695" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00235">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW144" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="329.0304" horizDistance="138.077" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00228">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW61" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="148.0017" horizDistance="133.943" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00227">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM06" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="148.0026" horizDistance="133.944" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00227">
<TargetPoint pntRef="GM06" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="149.1505" horizDistance="249.106" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00250">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW59" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="149.1451" horizDistance="249.106" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00250">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW59" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="160.2644" horizDistance="260.353" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00252">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW159" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="160.2659" horizDistance="260.353" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00252">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW159" />
</ReducedObservation>
<ReducedObservation setupID="liscadSAW160" azimuth="244.5944" horizDistance="52.087" azimuthType="measured" azimuthAccuracy="0.000300" distanceAccuracy="0.00210">
<TargetPoint pntRef="SAW60" />
</ReducedObservation>
</Survey>
</LandXML>
t:\ftemp>call xslt land.xml land.xsl 
liscadGM04
            pntRef  GM03   Min azimuth:70.0111
            pntRef  GM03   Max azimuth:70.0116
liscadGM04
            pntRef  SAW53   Min azimuth:252.3429
            pntRef  SAW53   Max azimuth:252.3442
liscadGM04
            pntRef  HB402   Min azimuth:309.3846
            pntRef  HB402   Max azimuth:309.3857
liscadGM04
            pntRef  GM05   Min azimuth:320.3911
            pntRef  GM05   Max azimuth:320.3917
liscadGM04
            pntRef  SAW144B   Min azimuth:348.0613
            pntRef  SAW144B   Max azimuth:348.0627
liscadGM04
            pntRef  SAW144   Min azimuth:35.4954
            pntRef  SAW144   Max azimuth:35.4957
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW61   Min azimuth:329.0304
            pntRef  SAW61   Max azimuth:329.0304
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  GM06   Min azimuth:148.0017
            pntRef  GM06   Max azimuth:148.0026
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW59   Min azimuth:149.1451
            pntRef  SAW59   Max azimuth:149.1505
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW159   Min azimuth:160.2644
            pntRef  SAW159   Max azimuth:160.2659
liscadSAW160
            pntRef  SAW60   Min azimuth:244.5944
            pntRef  SAW60   Max azimuth:244.5944

t:\ftemp>type land.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="obs" select="LandXML/Survey/ReducedObservation"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$obs">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                  generate-id($obs[@setupID=current()/@setupID][1])">
      <xsl:variable name="setups" 
                    select="$obs[@setupID=current()/@setupID]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="thisSetup" select="@setupID"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$setups">
        <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                      generate-id($setups[TargetPoint/@pntRef=
                                          current()/TargetPoint/@pntRef][1])">
          <xsl:value-of select="$thisSetup"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:variable name="points" 
                        select="$setups[TargetPoint/@pntRef=
                                        current()/TargetPoint/@pntRef]"/>
          <xsl:variable name="azimuths"
                        select="$points/@azimuth"/>
          <xsl:text>            pntRef  </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="TargetPoint/@pntRef"/>
          <xsl:text>   Min azimuth:</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$azimuths[not(.>$azimuths)][1]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;            pntRef  </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="TargetPoint/@pntRef"/>
          <xsl:text>   Max azimuth:</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$azimuths[not(.&lt;$azimuths)][1]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your response. No, I do not have to use Muenchian Grouping. From what I have been reading, that just seemed to be the suggested way to go. I have tried your code. Stepping through it in Altova XMLSpy it appears to be working and generating code, however if I leave it to run the application hangs, similar result in Dreamweaver. Not sure why. The original XML file is around 50,000 lines long, I'm wondering if the looping is inefficient? Could you explain the code to me? I am having a little trouble following what it is doing, Thanks Lee

Comment: Have you created a test XML file of, say, 1,000 lines and run it with that?  I suspect you are just running out of memory.  While you do that I will create a solution that uses keys.  The variable-based method does consume a lot of memory, whereas the key-based will consume less.  That may be the overriding factor for your particular situation.

Comment: The variable-based method establishes the population of items being grouped in a variable and then finds "the first in document order" from the variable by walking over the variable and checking each member.  Contrast this to the key-based method (Muenchian) where "the first in document order" is determined from looking up key values.  I tell my students that the multiple-level grouping *can* be done using the key-based method, but that the determination of keys can be a challenge.  Also, keys cannot be used when your population spans multiple input documents, but variables can.

Comment: Hi,Yes I have run it on a small set and it did work, but the full one is struggling. Thank you for all your help, invaluable!