# xsl muenchian grouping 3 levels I lost elements of 2nd level

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

I have been trying to understand muenchian grouping, but have some problems.

```
 <xsl:key name="CollectionPerson" match="av:Detail[av:Content != '' or av:Code != '']" use="concat(@BlockName,  '|', av:CollectionPerson)" />
 <xsl:key name="SubCollection" match="av:Detail[av:Content != '' or av:Code != '']" use="concat(@BlockName,  '|', av:CollectionPerson, '|', av:Collection_Id)" />

<xsl:key name="lv2" match="av:Detail[av:lv2]" use="concat(@BlockName, '|', av:lv2)" />
<xsl:key name="lv3" match="av:Detail[av:lv3]" use="concat(@BlockName, '|', av:lv3)" />
<xsl:key name="lv4" match="av:Detail[av:lv4]" use="concat(@BlockName, '|', av:lv4)" />
<xsl:key name="lv5" match="av:Detail[av:lv5]" use="concat(@BlockName, '|', av:lv5)" />
<xsl:key name="lv6" match="av:Detail[av:lv6]" use="concat(@BlockName, '|', av:lv6)" />
<xsl:key name="lv7" match="av:Detail[av:lv7]" use="concat(@BlockName, '|', av:lv7)" />
<xsl:key name="Collection_Id" match="av:Detail[@BlockName]" use="av:Collection_Id" />

<xsl:template name="create_block">
  <xsl:param name="block_name"/>
  <xsl:param name="element_link"/>
  <xsl:param name="filter_link"/>
  <xsl:param name="filter"/>
  <xsl:param name="collected_block"/>

  <xsl:variable name="elementf">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $filter_link)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element0">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element1">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link + 1)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element2">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link + 2)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element3">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link + 3)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element4">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link + 4)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element5">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link + 5)" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="element6">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('lv', $element_link + 6)" />
  </xsl:variable>


  <xsl:for-each select="av:Data/av:Part/av:ReportPart1/av:Details/av:Detail[@BlockName=$block_name and *[name() = $elementf] = $filter and generate-id(.)=generate-id(key($element0, concat(@BlockName, '|', *[name() = $element0])))]">
    <xsl:for-each select="key($element0, concat(@BlockName, '|', *[name() = $element0]))[@BlockName=$block_name and generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('CollectionPerson', concat(@BlockName, '|', av:CollectionPerson))[1])]">
      <xsl:element name="av:{*[name() = $element2]}">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('CollectionPerson', concat(@BlockName, '|', av:CollectionPerson))[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('SubCollection', concat(@BlockName, '|', av:CollectionPerson, '|', av:Collection_Id)))] ">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="av:Collection_Id=''">
              <xsl:call-template name="create_element">
                <xsl:with-param name="element_name" select="*[name() = $element3]"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:if test="*[name() = $element6]">
                <xsl:element name="av:{*[name() = $element3]}">
                  <xsl:element name="av:{*[name() = $element4]}">
                    <xsl:element name="av:{*[name() = $element5]}">
                      <xsl:for-each select="key('SubCollection',concat(@BlockName, '|', av:CollectionPerson, '|', av:Collection_Id))">
                        <xsl:sort select="av:Number"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="create_element">
                          <xsl:with-param name="element_name" select="*[name() = $element6]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

It skips all elements except first one, which do not have Collection_Id. 
In->>

```
<Detail BlockName="S">
  <Number>1000</Number>
  <Information>FirstName</Information>
  <Content>John</Content>
  <Code></Code>
  <lv1>S</lv1>
  <lv2>members</lv2>
  <lv3>member</lv3>
  <lv4>member_1</lv4>
  <lv5>FirstName</lv5>
  <CollectionPerson>2</CollectionPerson>
  <Collection_Id></Collection_Id>
</Detail>
<Detail BlockName="S">
  <Number>1100</Number>
  <Information>SecondName</Information>
  <Content>Smith</Content>
  <Code></Code>
  <lv1>S</lv1>
  <lv2>members</lv2>
  <lv3>member</lv3>
  <lv4>member_1</lv4>
  <lv5>SecondName</lv5>
  <CollectionPerson>2</CollectionPerson>
  <Collection_Id></Collection_Id>
</Detail> 
<Detail BlockName="S">
  <Number>1200</Number>
  <Information>Value</Information>
  <Content>100</Content>
  <Code></Code>
  <lv1>S</lv1>
  <lv2>members</lv2>
  <lv3>member</lv3>
  <lv4>member_1</lv4>
  <lv5>Acts</lv5>
  <lv6>Act</lv6>
  <lv7>Act_1</lv7>
  <lv8>Value</lv8>
  <CollectionPerson>2</CollectionPerson>
  <Collection_Id>101</Collection_Id>
</Detail>
```

Result

```
    <av:members>
      <av:member>
        <av:member_1>
          <av:FirstName>John</av:FirstName>
          <av:SecondName>Smith</av:SecondName>  <!-- This element not appear  -->
          <av:Acts>
            <av:Act>
              <av:Act_1>
                <av:Qty>10</av:Qty>
                <av:Value>100</av:Value>  
              </av:Act_1>
            </av:Act>
          </av:Acts>
          <av:member_1>
        <av:member>
      <av:members>
```

I'd appreciate any help as to where I'm going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Could you not simplify the example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process to expand Muenchian grouping to multiple levels:

- For the first level, create an `xsl-template` which matches the first key
- For each subsequent level, create a `for-each` which matches the key for that level
- For debugging, use attribute value templates to print unknown values

**References**

- [Multi-level Muenchian Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009149/1113772)
- [muenchian grouping in the second level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144139/1113772)
- [Muenchian Grouping - display second level base on row count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942147/1113772)
- [XSLT Grouping](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch06_02.htm)